# how to find mouseover and mouseout event for ipad or android

Tags: javascript

Touchevent is not working?

```
<div id="svgcontainer" style="width:200px; height:200px;border: 1px solid #222"></div>


$(function() {

var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("svgcontainer"));

var path = paper.path("M0,0 L150,0 L150,150, L0,150 Z");

path.attr({fill: 'red'});

var text = paper.text(40,20, "some text");

var group = paper.set();

group.push(path);
group.push(text);

group.mouseover(function(){path.attr({fill: 'green'})});

group.mouseout(function(){path.attr({fill: 'red'})});

});
```

Comment: I have not expected touchstart and touchend than I thing touchmove and  touchleave how to get event.